# YouTubeService Class throwing no such method Exception

Tags: java, youtube-api

I want to retrive the read only data from youtube using gData Java client but when I am trying to create the object of YouTubeService class it is throwing No Such Method Exception. Not able to find the resaon behind it.

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID);
```

Exception is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile.declareAdditionalNamespace(Lcom/google/gdata/util/common/xml/XmlWriter$Namespace;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

Make sure you have the right version.

Look at the stack trace ... If the exception appears when calling a method on an object in a library, you are most likely using separate versions of the library when compiling and running.

Make sure the class files that you are actually running are updated when you compile.

If the exception appears when calling a method on objects instantiated by classes you made, then your build process seems to be faulty.

Comment: Thank You @bhavik shah Really you have solved the problem boss. Actually what I am Doing instead of guava-14.0-rc1 Iam using google-collect-1.0 Jar file.